# does helm have feature of print?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

As we knew, helm charts are made by templates with variables and reference values from `values.yml`. I'd like to review the final heml chart, but there is no print or output feature.

For example, in serverless framework, I can run `sls print` to get the final `serverless.yml`

But I can't find the similar command in `heml`, such as

```
helm print <chart_name> -f values.yml
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make use of `--debug` and `--dry-run` option.

```
helm install ./mychart --debug --dry-run
```

Quoting statement from [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started.md) official doc.

> When you want to test the template rendering, but not actually install
> anything, you can use helm install ./mychart --debug --dry-run. This
> will send the chart to the Tiller server, which will render the
> templates. But instead of installing the chart, it will return the
> rendered template to you so you can see the output.

There is another way to do this without need of connection to tiller.

```
helm template ./mychart
```

### Update

Printing rendered contents of one of the stable chart (in my case airflow stable chart) would look like:

- Using `--debug` and `--dry-run` option

```
helm install --namespace "airflow" --name "airflow" stable/airflow --debug --dry-run -f values.yaml
```

- Using `helm template`

```
helm fetch stable/airflow
tar -xvf airflow-4.0.8.tgz
helm template --namespace "airflow" --name "airflow" ./airflow -f airflow/values.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I'd like to dry-run with one stable chart from github (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable), how the command looks like?

Comment: @Bill Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: `--debug` and `--namespace` are not must-have options. But it does show the use case, if I 'd like to add more options with helm, thanks.

Comment: The best answer is to use `helm template <chart>`

Comment: Yes, I don't use `install`, `helm template` is good enough

Answer (score 1):

#### updates

Somehow, directly run `helm template ./mychart` doesn't work any more with below error.

For example,

```
$ git clone git@github.com:helm/charts.git
$ cd charts/stable/datadog
$ helm template . 

Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: kube-state-metrics
```

There are two new files in this folders

```
requirements.yaml
requirements.lock
```

they both mentioned a repository called `https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/`

So we need add it in helm

```
helm repo add common https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com/
helm dependency update
helm template .
```

Now everything works as normal.

For your reference, my current helm version is v3.2.1.